# "cannot create instance defined in assembly" when creating a new System.Drawing.Icon

Tags: .net, wpf, icons, trayicon

I am trying to create a system tray icon in WPF using the lines of code below:

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("main.ico");
```

XAML:

```
> <Window x:Class="WpfExample.Window1"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
>     <Grid>
>         <Button Height="23" Margin="103,0,100,100" Name="button1"
> VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Submit</Button>
>         <TextBox Height="23" Margin="77,75,81,0" Name="textBox1"
> VerticalAlignment="Top" />
>     </Grid> </Window>
```

I've searched for a solution on Google but I'm trying to learn WPF and this is a problem I have hit when creating a system tray icon. The message I get is shown below:

> Cannot create instance of 'Window1'
>   defined in assembly 'WpfExample,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  Error in markup file
>   'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is complaining about the .xaml file but you posted the .cs file.

Comment: Added the XAML in now missed it off before - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small sample application that displays a tray icon. You can try to run it and study how the code works. I uploaded it to the SkyDrive:

http://cid-1fe4c9928da08eaa.office.live.com/self.aspx/P%c3%bablico/Tray-WpfApplication1.zip

Answer (score 1):

The .ico must be on a standard format, size, colors.
I had a issue with this.

Try to get and use this icon file and tell if it work:

http://www.iconarchive.com/download/visualpharm/must-have/Check.ico

There are more icons here:

http://www.iconarchive.com/category/system/must-have-icons-by-visualpharm.html

Comment: Ok, when you can have access to this .ico file and Save it on your computer, you will be able to try the solution.

Comment: Have grabbed the file will try it out tomorrow, thanks for assistance, hopefully it will resolve the issue :)

Comment: Just tried and still the same issue is present. I tried setting the size of the icon also to ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("main.ico", new System.Drawing.Size() { Height=25,Width=25 });